# .NET Core, Windows Azure Storage. Crashes on console app but not on web app?

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm not sure how much detail I can give with this as I don't have much to go off of. Basically, I have two apps. One is a console app for migrations and the other is a web app that actually displays my stuff. The web app works file the console app does not. On the console app, it will immediately exit with no exception on line 23.

Here is my console app:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;

namespace migration.Services
{
    public class AzureService
    {
        private CloudStorageAccount _storage;

        public AzureService()
        {
            _storage = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=MYACCOUNTNAME;AccountKey=PRETENDTHISISRIGHT");
        }

        public async Task<bool> CreateCampus(string name)
        {
            try
            {
                var client = _storage.CreateCloudBlobClient();

                //Should create a container (folder)
                var container = client.GetContainerReference(nameToContainer(name));
                await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        private string nameToContainer(string name)
        {
            var newName = name.Replace("-", "with").ToLower();
            newName = newName.Replace(" ", "-").ToLower();

            if (newName.Length < 3)
            {
                newName = newName + "-zz";
            }

            return newName;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my web app:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using mywebapp.Models;

namespace mywebapp.Services
{
    public class AzureService : IAzureService
    {
        private readonly AzureConfig _config;
        private readonly CloudStorageAccount _storage;

        public AzureService(IOptions<AzureConfig> config)
        {
            _config = config.Value;

            _storage = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(_config.connectionString);
        }

        public async Task<bool> CreateCampus(string name)
        {
            try
            {
                var client = _storage.CreateCloudBlobClient();

                //Should create a container (folder)
                var container = client.GetContainerReference(nameToContainer(name));
                await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        private string nameToContainer(string name)
        {
            var newName = name.Replace("-", "with").ToLower();
            newName = newName.Replace(" ", "-").ToLower();

            if (newName.Length < 3)
            {
                newName = newName + "-zz";
            }

            return newName;
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell, the only difference is I'm getting my connection string from appsettings in the web app but not in the console app. If it helps...
Console Project.Json File:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.1"
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "AWSSDK.Extensions.NETCore.Setup": "3.3.0.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1",
    "WindowsAzure.Storage": "7.2.1",
    "Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql": "1.0.1"
  },
  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    }
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net451+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  }
}
```

Web App Project.Json File:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
    "System.Net.Http": "4.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1",
    "AWSSDK.Extensions.NETCore.Setup": "3.3.0.1",
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.2",
    "Stormpath.AspNetCore": "0.8.1",
    "WindowsAzure.Storage": "7.2.1"
  },
  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    }
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },
  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "appsettings.Development.json",
      "appsettings.Production.json",
      "appsettings.Staging.json",
      "apiKey.properties",
      "stormpath.json",
      "uploads",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [
      "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%"
    ]
  }
}
```

Any ideas? I've tried this on Windows and Mac, various versions of the WindowsAzure.Storage library, .net core 1.0, 1.0.1 and 1.1. Neither Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code give me an exception. It just tells me my application closed with exit code 0.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you calling the async method? Are you perhaps calling from an async void method?

Comment: +1 I lost a good chunk of a day trying this out and debugging through it as a console app but it worked as a web app with exactly the same code! In both cases I am using ASP.NET Core 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, it may be the Microsoft.NETCore.App version doesn't match the project dependencies. We can check Microsoft.NETCore.App version from installation directory.

[image]

If the version of Microsoft.NETcore.App is 1.0.0, please have a try to change Microsoft.NETCore.App from 1.0.1 to 1.0.0 in the project.json. It works for me.

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "AWSSDK.Extensions.NETCore.Setup": "3.3.0.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1",
    "WindowsAzure.Storage": "7.2.1",
    "Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql": "1.0.1"
  },
```

We also can use Microsoft.NETcore.App 1.0.1 ,after we install it.  We can [download](https://download.microsoft.com/download/5/5/7/557D02A5-C3D0-4EF6-A570-4F75CD0DA5BF/DotNetCore.1.0.1-VS2015Tools.Preview2.0.2.exe)  it from [Microsoft official website](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows).
After install  Microsoft.NETcore.App 1.0.1 ,please try to add the **corresponding** runtimes in the project.json  file. . More about the .net core runtime category please refer the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/dotnet/articles/core/rid-catalog).

[image]

```
"runtimes": {
    "win10-x64": {}
  },
```

It also works successfully.

[image]